# Error dato indefinido PHP

Tags: php

Tengo esta clase

```
include_once('db.php');

class Menu extends Database {

  public function getUsuario($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = ?";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($id));

    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $resultado;  
  }
}
```

Y dentro de `home.php` hago esto

```
<?php
include_once('clases.php');

$blok = new Menu();

$id = 1;
$user = $blok->getUsuario($id);

echo 'Hola '.$user['nombre'];
?>
```

Y tengo este error `Notice: Undefined index: email in ..home.php on line 11`

Comment: Tienes un error en la linea 11 de home.php, cual es esa linea?

Comment: Es esta: `echo 'Hola '.$user['nombre'];`. Antes decia el email